# Why is this print function not outputting anything? (very new to python sorry)

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: screenshot]

I've just started learning python today and downloaded Pycharm, but even the simplest of commands aren't working at all. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: I cannot see your screen shot clearly. But are you sure you are compiling and running the current .py file? Since I see several .py files in your project. I tried the same code and it should run without any problem. Double check whether you are running the correct .py. Just right click the tab and run.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, in this case the image is useful. If the Asker would only have provided the code (which is `print('hello')`) we would even have less of a clue.

Comment: i'm sorry for any formatting issues, I'll make sure to take them into account in the future! i think i am running the correct .py file (i think its main.py?). i'll keep trying to fix it though, thank you all for your help

Comment: See this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#compound-configs Check whether your config is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#compound-configs) to check whether your config is correct. If you are running the correct .py file and it's not printing.

Go to  **Run>Edit Configurations** And select the **Emulate Terminal in output console** as in the picture below then it should give you output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I find another possible solution and updated my answer.

Comment: thank you so much! i redownloaded pycharm and tried out all your advice, and I believe its been fixed :D

Comment: Good, I think the your config might be incorrect, but you can always use emulate terminal to run it. If it helps you out, can you select my answer as the answer to the question?

Comment: of course! sorry i had to leave for a bit, thank you again